# How to fix "Specified Cast Is Not Valid" error when retrieving data from table to confirm if record exists?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, winforms

I'm using my program to add accounts to a database. I'm generating a random account number, checking if that account number exists in the database, and using it to create a new account if it doesn't. However, I am getting the error "Specified Cast Is Not Valid" on the line `Int32? RecordExist = (Int32?)check_Records.ExecuteScalar();`.

I have tried `.Convert.ToInt32`, just `int`, `double` and I have tried inspecting it as an object before the cast but I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
 string AccountNumber;
         bool accountExists = true;

        while (accountExists)
        {
            //GENERATE A RANDOM ACCOUNT NUMBER
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int acc1 = rnd.Next(0000, 9999);
            int acc2 = rnd.Next(0000, 9999);

            AccountNumber = "2000-" + acc1 + "-" + acc2 + ";";

            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                //CHECK WHETHER ACCOUNT NUMBER EXISTS. 
                string Query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE Account_Number = '" + AccountNumber + "'";

                using (MySqlCommand check_Records = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn))
                {
                       Int32? RecordExist = (Int32?)check_Records.ExecuteScalar();

                        if (RecordExist.HasValue && RecordExist.Value > 0)
                        {
                            //ACCOUNT EXISTS, GENERATE ANOTHER ACCOUNT NUMBER 
                            accountExists = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //ACCOUNT DOES NOT EXIST, USE ACCOUNT NUMBER
                            accountExists = false;
                            lblNewAccountNumber.Text = AccountNumber;
                        }
                    }

                    conn.Close();
```

Thanks for your help in advance, and I apologise if I've made any mistakes!

EDIT: The type I was casting to was incorrect, and using the immediate window I was able to see that it needed to be `Int64`. It now works! Thanks!

Comment: What do you get if you hold the `ExecuteScalar` value to an object variable(without any cast)?

Comment: @AmitKumar it returns `0`!

Comment: and what if you cast that object to `int` ? does it work?

Comment: if you assign to an object what type is it in the debugger (or look at RecordExist .GetType().Name)

Comment: Hi @AlexK and @AmitKumar I have done what you have suggested and the type was `Int64`, so I adjusted my code accordingly, and it now works! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to hold the `ExecuteScalar` value to an `object` type variable, then find out in debugging what is its type, and then apply the cast. As is mentioned by @Alex K in the comments section.
Hope it works.

Comment: I have done what you have suggested and the type was Int64, so I adjusted my code accordingly, and it now works! Thanks for the help!